# Does being under tension mean muscles are exerted?

Tags: pull-ups

I have a very bad understanding of how tension and rope works, so this may seem like a stupid question someone who does, but I ask anyway hoping people would be nice.

When we do a pullup, the bottom of our body is also under tension since we are raising the lower body up, so wouldn't this mean that the muscles of the lower body is also exerted?

Elaboration: [Consider this problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609822/model-to-understand-tension-varying-in-an-hanging-rope-with-mass). In it, we find that the tension in a hanging rope increases as we move up along it. If we approximate the human body as such a rope, shouldn't it mean that even at the lower body, some muscles would be recruited?

Or is it that this model doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### These are two different concepts of "tension"

What you describe is a tension in the rope that comes from the deadweight of the rope pulling down through gravity, which means there is a force applied to all parts of the rope simply by virtue of it having mass. The fibres of the rope holding up against that force is called "tension" in physics.

This physicist's sense of tension, of course, also applies to the human body. Ligaments, joint capsules, fascia, and bones (the passive movement apparatus) are more than enough to "hold against" this kind of tension for most cases, though. Otherwise, the body would rip apart if, e.g. carried or pulled when unconscious.

When you talk about tension *in human bodies*, though, you are talking about *muscle contraction*.

In a sense  such a thing happens additionally in pull-ups: Through stretch sensors, you also activate muscles (especially around the shoulders) which *actively* tense against the load to support the passive structures, even if you are "just hanging" there. That is an unconscious protective mechanism because the shoulder joint is comparatively instable and needs muscular stabilisation under heavier load. That's not necessary for the lower body though.

Therefore, no, your lower body does not have to exert energy in the sense of engaging muscles. There are forms of a pull-up where you actively engage the whole of the ventral chain (from the toes upwards). Actually, this often is considered "better" form. But that's very different from a rope just hanging there and keeping itself together against the gravitational force of its own mass.

Comment: Can you add details on last part?

Comment: @trystwithfreedom Many people suggest making kind of a plank when doing pull-ups, ie. you delierately tense the abdominal muscles and knee extensors and flex your hip slightly. Effectively, you straighten your legs and lift your feet a bit. That is supposed to help stability and muscular activation during pull-ups. That is not the same as your rope-idea

Answer (score 1):

**No**

When people talk about "muscular tension", they mean the muscle fibers are actively pulling against an opposing force. In a bicep curl, your biceps are actively pulling against the force of the weight attached at the arm. Likewise, the muscles in your forearm are actively pulling to maintain the position of the dumbbell. The cells that make up the muscle are activating to pull against the force.

In the case of your legs hanging in a pull-up, there is a passive tension applied on the muscle. That is true. Otherwise your body would continuously stretch to the floor. Your muscles (and bones, ligaments, and everything else), do not actively engage to fight gravity in this manner. They are simply strong enough to not tear apart from the forces of gravity acting upon it, similar to how a rope just hangs and doesn't need any active engagement to exist.

Answer (score 0):

> When we do a pullup, the bottom of our body is also under tension since we are raising the lower body up

No. I’m not sure where you’re getting this idea. Pull-ups don’t use the legs. I don’t really know how else to explain that. Your arm is hanging off your shoulder at all times, but your forearms aren’t exhausted from just existing.

Answer (score 0):

The tension in the lower body in a pull-up is transmitted through the bones and ligaments, not the muscles, so it doesn't require exertion. Bones and ligaments are effectively passive structures that can transmit forces without needed to consume energy to do so, unlike muscles which need energy in order to be able to contract, but they can produce tension rather than merely transmitting it.